# Is transit visa required for London Heathrow Terminal 2 to 3?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, dublin, mumbai

I am an Indian national who will be travelling to Mumbai from Dublin through London Heathrow Airport on December 10th 2022 and will be returning on Jan 13th 2023.

I will be travelling from Dublin to London by Aer Lingus and from London to Dublin by Virgin Atlantic.My Baggage will be checked through. My flight will land at LHR Terminal 2 and my next flight is from LHR Terminal 3. I have an Irish Residence Permit card.

My question is, will I need to get a Transit Visa to travel from LHR Terminal 2 to LHR Terminal 3?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have checked it out and I am a bit confused about this exemption: a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland. I have an Irish residency permit and was wondering if I'll be exempted due to that

Comment: Note that at London Heathrow there is airside transit (between those terminals), whereas at London Stansted, there is no airside transit (even with its single terminal).

Comment: There is a [UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa) which guides you through a transit visa application. It also links to [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) (although that doesn't list the exemptions).

Comment: Ireland (Republic) is a [member](https://www.litrg.org.uk/tax-guides/migrants/eu-and-eea-countries) of both the European Economic Area and the European Union.

Comment: @ListonLucioMascarenhas This is a question-and-answer site, and you've now asked a different question: whether the Irish residence permit you have is a "common format residence permit." Please use the "Ask Question" button (found on most pages) and ask that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll consider this solved